# How can I reference form elements by 2 in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'd like to dynamically add form elements as key/value pairs on a form. To do so, I made a formbuilder array and then iterated through an object and added its keys and values to the form array. Now I'm trying to reference them and I can't seem to get a handle on it. What's the best way to reference these?

code for building the form:

```
this.individualForm = this.fb.group(
  newI);
  this.attrArr = this.fb.array([]);
  this.individualForm.addControl('attrArr',this.attrArr);
  Object.keys(this.attr).forEach((key)=>{
    console.log(key);
    console.log(this.attr[key]);
    this.attrArr.push(this.fb.group({//form group
      key:[key],//first form element
      value:[this.attr[key]]
    }))
  });
  console.log(this.individualForm);
```

code for iterating the form array:

```
<div formArrayName="attrArr">
     <div *ngFor="let fg of attrArr.controls; let i=index">
           {{i}} 
           {{attrArr.controls[i].controls['key']}}
           <input type="text" [formControlName]="attrArr.controls[i].controls['key']">

       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by reference here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `formGroupName`. Can you try:

```
<div formArrayName="attrArr">
     <div *ngFor="let fg of attrArr.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
           {{i}} 
           {{attrArr.controls[i].controls['key']}}
           <input type="text" [formControlName]="attrArr.controls[i].controls['key']">
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Network, when you work using "dynamic" form. you need take account you has two object: the formControl itself and the object that generate the formControl.

Futhermore, I think you don't want to create a FormArray, just a formGroup. That's, imagine your object is some like

```
{"name":"Peter","surname":"Smith"}
```

I think you want get something like

```
 myForm=new FormGroup({
     name:new FormControl('Peter'),
     surname:new FormControl('Smith'),
 })
```

So,

```
  //I want have an array with the names of the fields, called fields
  this.individualForm = new FormGroup(); //declare as FormGroup
  this.fields=[]; //iitialize the array

  Object.keys(this.attr).forEach((key)=>{
    this.individualForm.addControl(key,new FormControl(this.attr[key])
    this.field.push(key);
  }
```

Then, we can iterate over "fields"

```
<div [formGroup]="individualForm ">
     <div *ngFor="let fg of fields; let i=index">
           {{i}}.-{{fg}} 
           <input type="text" [formControlName]="fg">
       </div>
 </div>
```

See that I create a empty FormGroup, and use [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) to add a control. I add the "names of the controls" to an array when I iterate over the keys, but you can make *ngFor over the object using pipe key and forget create this "auxiliar" array